# On-click (check appears) action is performed, second click (check disappears) action is performed again. Need, second click to delete first action

Tags: javascript, function

```
<body>
    <h1 align="center">Safety Summary Generator</h1>
    <table style="width:">
        <tr>
            <th height="200" width="150">
                <div id="CEC">
                    <img src="../CHEMICAL EXPOSURE - CORROSIVE.png" alt="CHEMICAL EXPOSURE - 
                CORROSIVE" width="100" height="100">
                        <p>CHEMICAL EXPOSURE - CORROSIVE</p>
                    </div>
```

The user selects the radio button and the action is performed and a check appears. Currently when the radio is selected a second time it performs the action again but the check is removed. I need the second click to delete the first action.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Load" onClick="addRow('CEC', 1)">
</th>undefined</tr>undefined</table>undefined<h3 align="center">(Safety summary print sheet below)</h3>undefined<div>undefined<h1>
<hr color="#00cc00" width="100%">
</h1>
<div id="printDiv">
    <table id="2table" border="1">
        <h2>Chemical Hazards</h2>
        <thead id="2table-head"></thead>
        <tbody id="2table-body"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<h1>
    <hr color="#00cc00" width="100%">
    </h1>
    <div align="center">
        <input type="button" onclick="PSSSReset()" value="PSSS/HWDI Delete">
        </div>
        <br>
            <h3 align="center" style="color: red">Caution: Be sure to review the print sheet (between the 
            green lines) before pressing the Print Safety Summary button. You can only print once before 
            refreshing the browser.</h3>
            <div align="center">
                <button id="doPrint">Print Saftey Summary</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
//Table row and column
```

Need event listener to identify first click and perform the below function.
Need event listener to identify second click and delete fist click function and reset.

```
 "use strict";
var t_names = ["1table-body", "2table-body", "3table-body", "4table-body"];
var counter = [0, 0, 0, 0];

function addRow(v_id, t_id) {
    var t_string = t_names[t_id];
    console.log(t_string)
    var tableBody = document.getElementById(t_string);
    //find last row
    var row = tableBody.rows[tableBody.rows.length - 1];
    //if the row has six cells or there are no rows create a new one
    if (row === null || row === undefined || row.cells.length >= 6) {
        row = document.createElement("tr");
        tableBody.appendChild(row);
    }
    //create new cell
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    //add data to cell
    th.innerHTML = document.getElementById(v_id).innerHTML;
    //add cell to row
    row.appendChild(th);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your code, here is the [UPDATED_FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nfr5jqz1/)

***HTML***

I changed the input element to call updateTable() and pass an extra argument of `this`.

```
<body>
    <h1 align="center">Safety Summary Generator</h1>
    <table style="width:">
        <tr>
            <th height="200" width="150">
                <div id="CEC">
                    <img src="../CHEMICAL EXPOSURE - CORROSIVE.png" alt="CHEMICAL EXPOSURE - 
                CORROSIVE" width="100" height="100">
                        <p>CHEMICAL EXPOSURE - CORROSIVE</p>
                    </div>

               <input type="checkbox" value="Load" onClick="updateTable('CEC', 1, this)">
</th>undefined</tr>undefined</table>undefined<h3 align="center">(Safety summary print sheet below)</h3>undefined<div>undefined<h1>
<hr color="#00cc00" width="100%">
</h1>
<div id="printDiv">
    <table id="2table" border="1">
        <h2>Chemical Hazards</h2>
        <thead id="2table-head"></thead>
        <tbody id="2table-body"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<h1>
    <hr color="#00cc00" width="100%">
    </h1>
    <div align="center">
        <input type="button" onclick="PSSSReset()" value="PSSS/HWDI Delete">
        </div>
        <br>
            <h3 align="center" style="color: red">Caution: Be sure to review the print sheet (between the 
            green lines) before pressing the Print Safety Summary button. You can only print once before 
            refreshing the browser.</h3>
            <div align="center">
                <button id="doPrint">Print Saftey Summary</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

***JS***

I created a new function called updateTable() which takes the same two parameters as addTable() plus receives `this` element and stores it as thisCheckbox.

updateTable() checks if the table is empty.  If it is, it calls addRow() and passes the vid and tid parameters.

Also just to be safe, sets the "checked" status of the checkbox to true (so the box will be checked in the UI).

If the table is not empty, updateTable() calls delRow() and passes it the table element.  It also makes sure the checkbox is unchecked.

The addRow() function, I did not change.

The delRow() function is just a `while` loop that deletes every row of the table until it is empty.

Hope this Helps!  Let me know if you have any questions.  :)

```
var t_names = ["1table-body", "2table-body", "3table-body", "4table-body"];
var counter = [0, 0, 0, 0];


function updateTable(vid, tid, thisCheckbox) {
   var t_string = t_names[tid];
   var tableBody = document.getElementById(t_string);
    //check if table is empty
   if (tableBody.rows.length === 0) {
        //table is empty so regardless of checkbox state
        //checkbox needs to be checked now as we are going
        //to add the row
        thisCheckbox.checked = true;
        addRow(vid, tid);
    } else {
        //table is not empty so make sure checkbox is unchecked
        //then remove the row
        thisCheckbox.checked = false;
        delRow(tableBody);
    }
}
function delRow(tableBody) {
    while (tableBody.rows.length > 0) {
        tableBody.deleteRow(0);
    }
}

function addRow(v_id, t_id) {
    var t_string = t_names[t_id];
    console.log(t_string)
    var tableBody = document.getElementById(t_string);
    //find last row
    var row = tableBody.rows[tableBody.rows.length - 1];
    //if the row has six cells or there are no rows create a new one
    if (row === null || row === undefined || row.cells.length >= 6) {
        row = document.createElement("tr");
        tableBody.appendChild(row);
    }
    //create new cell
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    //add data to cell
    th.innerHTML = document.getElementById(v_id).innerHTML;
    //add cell to row
    row.appendChild(th);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input Brian. I am not a programmer and am just starting to build my Javascript knowledge. Could you assist me in incorporating the doWork function into the addrow function?

Comment: @PaulHauer  Sure thing,  just set up a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lvg5n1ot/ and will update my answer with code.

Comment: @PaulHauer Answer Updated.  Please check it out.  :)

Comment: Thanks Brian. It works great. The problem now is that in the full application has many check boxes that go to multiple tables. Is there a variable that I can use in place of "chkUpdateTable" or can I put multiple IDs with in the ("chkUpdateTable")?

Comment: @PaulHauer I thought you might run into that.   I have updated the code and the link to the fiddle.   It no longer uses the two constants I had added before.    Let me know if that helps.   Also, can you give me an upvote and click the checkmark to the left of my answer if I helped solve your problem :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers